# Start matlab command window without losing focus

Tags: windows, matlab

Is possible to start Matlab without losing focus? If from the cmd prompt I run:

```
matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -nosplash -minimize -wait
```

the Matlab command window opens as a minimized window but it steals focus from the Windows command prompt.

**Edit:** I do want to have the `-wait` flag.

Answer (score 0):

I found this Windows command line tool, [cmdow](http://www.commandline.co.uk/cmdow/), that allows you to manipulate windows. You can act on individual windows using the hexcode handle or caption. After I typed this in the command line :

```
cmdow /run matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -nosplash -minimize -wait
```

You can launch MATLAB. And then if you come back to the original command window and typed in this:

```
cmdow /T
```

You'd see:

[image: cmdow example]

The image named MATLAB is the true MATLAB Command Window and the image named matlab is actually another command line window launched by cmdow that calls MATLAB. The image name reflects the command you put in and the caption reflects where the executable for this command resides.

You can then make this command window active by typing in

```
cmdow *MATLAB\R2014b\bin* /ACT
```

`*MATLAB\R2014b\bin*` is to tell `cmdow` to look for windows that has caption matching this pattern. `/ACT` is to make it active.

So, to make this process automatic. I'd use text editor to make a batch file, for example, `test.bat` that has these codes(of course you'll need to change according to your system configuration):

```
cmdow /run matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -nosplash -minimize -wait
cmdow *MATLAB\R2014b\bin* /ACT
```

Then in command line window, execute this batch file by typing in

```
test.bat
```

You'll see a new command line window popping up as active window, along with a minimized MATLAB command window.

P.S. You may have to disable your antivirus program so cmdow can work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I don't understand how to apply it to solve my particular problem.

Comment: I've provided more detailed steps, please see updated answer.

Comment: Can you see if the behavior changes if you add a `-wait` flag after `-minimize`? Btw what Matlab and Windows versions are you using? I'm using Matlab R2014a and Windows 8.1

Comment: Yes. with the addition of `-wait`, the command window waits for MATLAB to terminate. Even if you click on command window, you can't do anything because it is waiting for MATLAB to finish. I'm using Windows 7 and MATLAB 2014b. But if you add `-wait`, you're actively giving focus and control away. I don't think there's a fix for that because that's exactly what you told it to do.

Comment: I''ll will edit my question accordingly. I do want to give matlab control (i.e wait for it to finish) but I don't want the command window to steal focus from the command prompt.